# Thymleaf: Print Number of Table Entries for Current Month

Tags: html, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am looking to print the number of rows in a table for the current month using Thymeleaf.

My current code prints out the following display:

[image]

When ideally I'm looking for it to display this:

[image]

My code can be found below:

```
<div th:each="project:${projectList}">
    <div th:if="${#dates.format(project.enddate, 'MM')} == ${#calendars.format(#calendars.createNow(), 'MM')}">
        <div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800" th:text="${#lists.size(project)}"></div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is probably easier to just calculate the total in your controller and add an extra attribute in the model to display.

```
@GetMapping
public String myControllerMethod(Model model) {
  ...
  model.addAttribute("totalCurrentMoth", calculateTotalOfCurrentMonth());

  return "overview"; // change to what your view is actually called
}
```

And replace your HTML code with:

```
<div th:text="${totalCurrentMonth}"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely accomplish this with a combination of collection [selection](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-collection-selection) & [projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-collection-projection) along with the Thymeleaf utility objects.  I'm guessing something like this would work? (It appears you're treating `project` as both a list an and object in your example, so I'm guessing a little bit here.)

```
<span
  th:with="currentMonth=${#calendars.format(#calendars.createNow(), 'MM')}"
  th:text="${#lists.size(projectList.?[#dates.format(enddate, 'MM') == #root.currentMonth])}" />
```

If projectList really is a list of lists, something like this may work:

```
<span th:text="${#aggregates.sum(projectList.![size()])}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this out with the help of @Wim Deblauwe 's advice.

I created a query in my Repository file which returned a list of all projects whose month matched the current month, as so:

```
@Query("SELECT p, a FROM Project p JOIN p.user a WHERE a.username = :username AND MONTH(p.enddate) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)")
    List<Project> findAllProjectsByCurrentUsernameAndEnddate(@Param("username") String username);
```

I then found the number of entries within this list in my services file:

```
public int getNumberofProjectsByYear(String username) {
        return projectRepository.findAllProjectsByCurrentUsernameAndEnddate(username).size();
    }
```

From there I was able to add this to my model within my controller:

```
@GetMapping({ "/", "/index", "/dashboard" })
public String dashboard(Model model, Principal principal) {
   int noOfProjectsCurrentMonth = 
   projectService.getNumberofProjectsByYear(principal.getName());

   model.addAttribute("noOfProjectsCurrentMonth", noOfProjectsCurrentMonth);

return "index";
    }
```

And call it as follows within my html template:

```
<div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800" th:text="${noOfProjectsCurrentMonth}"></div>
```

Comment: Maybe you can do `SELECT COUNT(p) FROM Project p...` to avoid returning the full objects only to get the size of the list?